# Fetching data from running application

Tags: linux, memory, process, memory-mapping, virtual-address-space

Is there an efficient method to find specific data in the memory of a running application on Linux?

So far, I found that I can use `/proc/[pid]/maps` to access the memory of the running application. But how can I find specific data in it? For example, if the running application is firefox, how could I find the html code of the current window? Or how could I at least find the title of the current firefox window?

Is there a solution to find virtual addresses of variables containing known data? Could I use D-bus to achieve any of this?

In most cases, the data I would like to fetch is displayed in a GUI, if that makes it any easier.

Comment: One program can not access others memory (an exception is shared memory ) It is basic principle of every operating system . else it is considered as vulnerability of OS.

Comment: You could tried to use some Web scraping tools or Selenium kind of tools , which will grab data from GUI , not from memory .

Comment: I don't want to use Selenium because it is pretty slow + it requires me to use Selenium to start firefox, which is not convinient. I've used Selenium in many projects and it's amazing but it definitely isn't what I want for this one unfortunately.